# How can I code this with less SQL queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

These code outputs 2 sql queries.

```
@trackings = Tracking.where(:target_user_id => current_user.id ).page(params[:page]).per(10)
@trackings_count = Tracking.where(:target_user_id => current_user.id ).count
```

To make it less, how can I code?

something like this?

```
@trackings = Tracking.where(:target_user_id => current_user.id )
@trackings_count = @trackings.count
@trackings = @trackings.page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Comment: I think your second attempt will still result in two queries because the ".count" runs a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ..."

Comment: @Nick Thanks. Do you have any good idea to make it faster to load the page

Comment: I can suggest if you can post your model code. Do you have association like TargetUser has_many :trackings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use counter_cache. It will help you save multiple queries. You need not to run another query for count.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Answer (score 1):

My solution (One query). I guess you using kaminari gem :

```
@trackings = Tracking.where(:target_user_id => current_user.id).to_a
@trackings_count = @trackings.length
@trackings = Kaminari.paginate_array(@trackings).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```